# Rotation of axes give the same point in space?

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

I am playing around with rotation of axes formulas and not getting it. I don't understand how this rotates anything when it is just giving you different coordinates for the SAME point in space. How can anything be rotated when it's giving the same points each time?

Answer (score 1):

In Figure 1 of http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Vectors/upfiles/RotationofAxes.pdf we see that indeed the point P doesn't move (at least with respect to the page on which the figure is drawn). But while the $y$-axis goes straight up and down on the page, the $Y$-axis is leaning to the left; and while the $x$-axis runs directly right and left in a level line on the page, the $X$-axis is tilted so it is higher on the right and lower on the left.

Suppose you had a sheet of transparent plastic with a rectangular grid (like graph paper) printed on it.  You could align this grid with the $x$ and $y$ axes (so two of the lines on the grid lie exactly on those two axes) by laying the transparent sheet carefully on the page where the figure is drawn.  But if you later want to align that grid with the $X$ and $Y$ axes instead, you will have to rotate the transparent sheet somehow in order to make the lines of the grid lie on those new axes.

In short, the figure is illustrating a rotation of the *axes*. Instead of the original axes (and their associated grid), we use a new set of axes oriented in a different direction.  Things that are not the axes (such as point P, whose position is being measured relative to the axes) don't move.

Comment: Ok so how does this rotate the entire graph when you substitute in the formulas if this doesn't rotate the point? I'm confused...

Comment: I mean isn't this just another way of describing this point in space? Like polar coordinates, you get the same graph but a different way? How is this rotating anything when it's giving the same points?

Comment: Technically, you are right, really nothing in the graph rotates at all. But the $X$ and $Y$ axes are the image of what the $x$ and $y$ axes _would_ look like if we could rotate them both counterclockwise.  That's why I suggested taking some object that is _not_ attached to the graph and laying it on the graph.  Try this with an actual printout of the graph on paper and a convenient object with a square corner.  Line up the square corner with the $x$ and $y$ axes.  Now line it up with the $X$ and $Y$ axes.  How do you do that?  You have to rotate the object.

Comment: So this picture just gives a relationship then? If so then this makes sense because then every x and y value can be changed into something in terms of X and Y, that way you get the same exact points on the XY system as you get in the xy system, in other words you would get the same graph but it's rotated, right?

Comment: I think you've got it! Yes, I believe that is an accurate description of the math.